# 403 forbidden access to my whole site

Tags: errors

Yesterday I tried to add some lines of code to my `functions.php` and suddenly the whole site throw 403 forbidden error. Both frontend/admin. Asked my hosting provider ( SiteGround ) and they said it is blocked because of security reasons as far as I understood. How can I check for malwares if I can't access my admin panel to install plugin for this. Also downloaded the files on my local server ( I am using LAMP stack on Ubuntu 18 ) and when I try to reach my local domain it redirects me to the site again with 403 forbidden error. What I tried to add as code is :

```
function test() {
   echo "TEST";
}
add_action("test", "test")
```

After that I have deleted it through FTP. Hope I explained the situtation clearly. If you need more info to give me some advice will provide it immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at all files via your hosting File Manager (or FTP). Look for any code that shouldn't be there.

See my answer to [Coinhive Malware on WordPress websites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346813/coinhive-malware-on-wordpress-websites/346821#346821) , of things to check.

And here's the process I use to clean up hacked WP sites: https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ . Basically: change credentials on everything; look at all file contents for hacked code; reinstall everything from known good/original source; reinstall latest WP; and more.

Comment: Thank you very much!